# Oracle ADF vs a Javascript MVC framework like EmberJs or AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js, oracle-adf

I am starting a new project that has planned to use a large of Oracle components BEPL, SOA Suit, Oracle Spatial and Oracle ADF.  I am trying to convince the team that a Javascript framework like EmberJs or AngularJs would  be better.  I feel like I might not be comparing apples to apple with EmberJs vs ADF.  The goal of the project is to expose a large complex database to both our Web Front end and as an API.  I think that a Javascript framework would work well with the data being exposed as an API instead of thought ADF where it might use a more proprietary connector.

Comment: Are you asking a particular question?  Or are you just hoping someone else has done something similar and looking for reassurance?  If So, Do it, the web is moving in this direction ;)

Comment: It has been a year and a half of working with AngularJS over ADF.  And I am happy with the decision.  
We have build a robust middle API Webservice to support the Angular frontend.  This allowed for a good separation of responsibilities and automated testing.   
The angular framework give us lots of flexibility in displaying the data and being data driven.  We have so many objects in tables that we build a lot of the ui dynamically based on a description of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be subjective with my answer here, as ADF is a very big framework and **CAN** be used along with EmberJS if you want to ditch the ADF Faces part, however here is my 5 cents into this

## Using EmberJS from a Java Developer point of view

### Pros

- If done right, a great User Experience can be generated.
- Very flexible front end development for your front end team.
- More options when it comes to Deployment on servers as you don't need to work with Java EE container (I'm excluding the Service part of course).

### Cons

- Developers will need to learn EmberJS, Backbone or AngularJS
- Developers will have to provide a great service layer, and controller in a way that all this JS Frameworks can interact with.
- Developers will have to consider security constraints themselves as JS is not secure by default.
- Development time will increase greatly and if you are under a deadline it'll be very hard to be met since developers will have to take care of everything themselfs.

Answer (score 4):

Well.. comparing cars to bikes always look crazy. However sometimes you choose bike over the car. And sometimes you might want even reinvent the wheel.

However mostly it just shows lack of particular knowledge and very bad decision is trying to get rid of native, supported solution and start repeating it with the tools, you know better.

All oracle stuff now driven with ADF. There should be VERY strong reasons to abandon it. And you didn't provided any.

Answer (score 1):

This question interested me, so I made a tiny research. If you make a search on tags [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) + [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle), you'll notice that there are only 74 questions tagged. So these technologies do not actually intersect quite often in a real world and it's doubtful if anyone would provide expertise.

I'm learning AngularJS now and I'm quite certain that it's worth every minute I spend on it, it will be there for a long time and that it provides one of the quickest an intuitive developing experiences on the market. It requires learning, though, and even hair-pulling at times if you're a novice, like I was.

PS One of the killer arguments are the numbers for the tags in this question in the top-right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing ADF to JS is like comparing Servlets/JSP to JS. Makes no sense.
ADF generates JS as part of its page rendering, but also allows you to incorporate JS and JS libraries to extend and augment the ADF JSF page functionality.
I suggest you read a bit about JSF before making this decision...or comparison.
AND, if you're working with Oracle, specifically Fusion Apps, which is written in ADF and SOA Suite, (BTW: BPEL is one component of SOA Suite, not a separate product), then you have no choice but to use ADF.
Seems you have some study ahead of you.